# How to get Midlet version in lwuit?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp

I have the jad file with following description

```
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 404071
MIDlet-Jar-URL: test.jar
MIDlet-Name: test
MIDlet-Vendor: Vendor
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.1
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MicroEdition-test: test
```

How to get `MIDlet-Version` through code?

I have tried System.getProperty("MIDlet-Version"), but it returns null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your MIDlet subclass

```
String version = getAppProperty("MIDlet-Version");
```

Extracted from:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?153128-MIDlet-Version

Comment: Thanks for reply jmunoz, but i need to do it on lwuit, what you have suggested is for native j2me

Comment: LWUIT is graphic library for j2me. The code that I give to you, will work fine.

Comment: Thanks jmunoz, I was trying it outside midlet, it works fine within midlet. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

System.getProperty("MIDlet-Version") will works only in midlet or by calling from midlet instance.